# Spring Expression Language condtional application properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a value from the application properties file with condtional. If property a doesn't exits take property b.

But I can't get it to work. I have read about "SPEL" but cannot really understand it. I have tried this

```
@Value("'${api.path}' ?: '${api.backuppath}'")
private String path;
```

This doesnt work because it needs value on both property to work. In my case the first property can be null or the second can be null.

Comment: Is this a conditional/ternary expression?  `@Value("#{2 > 1 ? 'a' : 'b'}") // 'a'`.  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language

Comment: ok i got it to work. It has to be in #{ } didnt know that. Thanks